# What controls how quickly changes to ES are visible?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are trying to tune the time that updates take to show up in Elastisearch.

We have refresh_interval set to 300ms, and based on elasticsearch internal metrics the external refresh time for our index is between 200ms-300ms.

But when trying to measure this externally by doing an update followed by select we see latency between 800-1500ms. Any ideas what else is at play here or pointers what to look into?

Some more data, the index in question has 32 shards with 1 replica. Shard sizes are between 10-20gb.

A typical update for us is just reinserting a document with a few fields changed. I am not sure what counts as a big document, but we have roughly 200 fields on each document. In the test case where we measure this, we just do a single such update.

Comment: Can you give an example about `by doing an update`? how do you update your data?

Comment: Added it to the description too but:

A typical update for us is just reinserting a document with a few fields changed. I am not sure what counts as a big document, but we have roughly 200 fields on each document. In the test case where we measure this, we just do a single such update.

Comment: How do you `reinserting` the data?
Are you using logstash?
Are you using `_bulk` API ?

If you are using `_bulk` API try to add **?refresh** parameter to refresh immediately. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk-api-query-params

`POST _bulk?refresh`

Comment: We are using _bulk. I will test with that, thanks

Comment: Please let me know the results

Comment: Using refresh I observe latency between 250ms and 1000ms which is better though those at 1 second still seem slow. There is also the concern of practicality of requiring to use refresh